# Recursive function for CPI

Tags: python, function, recursion, economics

Having a play around trying to better understand recursion. I want to make a function that shows the CPI increase for a particular year given a starting amount.

Assuming the starting amount is 100000 and CPI rate is 5%, then f(0) = 100000, f(1) = 5000, f(2) = 5250 etc.I want to return the CPIincrease column from below

```
                               rate  0.05
n   TotalCPI    CPIincrease 
0   100000      
1   105000      5000    
2   110250      5250    
3   115762.5    5512.5  
4   121550.625  5788.125    
5   127628.1563 6077.53125  
6   134009.5641 6381.407812 
7   140710.0423 6700.478203 
8   147745.5444 7035.502113 
9   155132.8216 7387.277219 
10  162889.4627 7756.64108
```

So far I have the TotalCPI from column of the above table

```
def CPIincreases(n):
    if n<=0:
        return initial
    else:
        return (CPIincreases(n-1))*(1+CPIrate)

initial = 100000
CPIrate = 0.05

print(CPIincreases(1),CPIincreases(2),CPIincreases(3),CPIincreases(4))
output: 105000.0 110250.0 115762.5 121550.625
```

Now I'm lost. Because the output shows the I should be adding in

```
CPIincrease(n) - CPIincrease(n-1)
```

Somewhere.

Any Help greatly appreciated, even if its to say this function is not possible.

Cheers

Comment: Your formula is wrong in `CPIincreases()` (and it is not a proper function... you should make it independent of `initial` and `CPIrate` directly).

Comment: @norok2 what do you mean?

Comment: Look @JonBetts answer. It is very close to what I would have written. The aspect of making your function independent means that it is bad practice to have functions using variables defined outside the function itself, like your code does with e.g `initial` and `CPIrate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you have created calculates the total value of the lump sum over time, and as you have pointed out, you can call it twice (once with `year` and once with `year - 1`) and take the difference to get your answer.

If you really want do this recursively in one go we need to think through the base cases:

- Year 0: At the beginning there is no interest

  - `return 0`
- Year 1: After the first year the change is just the initial amount times the interest rate

  - `return initial * rate`
- Year 2+: From this year on, we make the same as last year, plus the interest on that interest

  - `return last_year + rate * last_year`
  - Or just: `return  last_year * (1 + rate)`

Now we can put it all together:

```
def cpi_increase(year, initial, rate):
    if year == 0:
        return 0

    if year == 1:
        return initial * rate

    return (1 + rate) * cpi_increase(year - 1, initial, rate)
```

If we print this out we can see the values about match up:

```
initial = 100000
rate = 0.05

for year in range(11):
    print('{year:<5} {total:<21} {cpi_increase}'.format(
        year=year,
        total=initial * (1 + rate) ** year,
        cpi_increase=cpi_increase(year, initial, rate)
    ))
```

The values:

```
0     100000.0              0
1     105000.0              5000.0
2     110250.0              5250.0
3     115762.50000000001    5512.5
4     121550.62500000003    5788.125
5     127628.15625000003    6077.53125
6     134009.56406250005    6381.407812500001
7     140710.04226562506    6700.478203125001
8     147745.5443789063     7035.502113281251
9     155132.8215978516     7387.2772189453135
10    162889.4626777442     7756.64107989258
```

Thinking through our base cases also shows how to create the direct calculation. At year `y` we have applied the `(1 + rate)` multiplication `y - 1` times and the base `(initial * rate)` once. This gives us:

```
def cpi_increase_direct(year, initial, rate):
    if year <= 0:
        return 0

    return initial * rate * (1 + rate) ** (year - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

I like how Jon's answers is more elaborate. Here's my code, I've tried to make variable names self explanatory but I'll briefly describe them as well.

```
total_cpi: first column
cpi_increase: 2nd column
cpi_rate: CPIrate
```

If we need to solve it in one recursive function, we can solve this problem only by using state variables:-

```
def calculate_cpi_increase(total_cpi, cpi_increase, year):
    if year == 0:
        return total_cpi, cpi_increase
    else:
        return calculate_cpi_increase(total_cpi*(1+cpi_rate), total_cpi*cpi_rate, year-1)

cpi_rate = 0.05

calculate_cpi_increase(100000, 0, 10)
```

result: (162889.46267774416, 7756.641079892579)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should not call a recursive function with all the values that you want to print. For example if you call `F(2)`,`F(3)`,`F(4)` and `F(5)` you would repeat the calculations for `F(2)` 4 times, as every other call needs this calculation.

You should not use global variables also, you can use my simple approach and encapsulate them in another function. In this code I generate not only one value, this generates the full table, a list of python tuples. Any tuple are two values, the value and the increment per iteration. The full table is printed by another function.

```
def CPITable(n, initial = 100000, CPIrate = 0.05):

    def CPITableRecurse(n):
        if n<=0:
            return [(initial,0)]
        else:
            CPI = CPITable(n-1)
            inc = CPI[-1][0] * CPIrate
            CPI.append((CPI[-1][0] + inc , inc ))
            return CPI

    return CPITableRecurse(n)


def printTable(table):
    i = 0
    for line in table:
        print ( str(i) + " %5.2f %5.2f" % line)
        i += 1


printTable(CPITable(6))
#output: 
#   0 100000.00  0.00
#   1 105000.00 5000.00
#   2 110250.00 5250.00
#   3 115762.50 5512.50
#   4 121550.62 5788.12
#   5 127628.16 6077.53
#   6 134009.56 6381.41
```